# Encrypt files in UWP apps

Tags: c#, encryption, uwp

I'm working on a **file encryption UWP app** on Windows. I found a way to do that in a blogpost and tried it with little modifications. But it always fails. I don't know what's wrong with the code.

I'm a beginner to UWP apps. I tried different methods to encrypt files. If there's any better way to do file encryption on UWP platform please mention them too.

It shows following exception:-

> Exception from HRESULT : 0XC0000225

(When a user click a button it shows a dialog box and when user hit OK I need to encrypt the selected file.)

```
        if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
        {
            // Encrypt the file.
            try { 
            IBuffer data = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(storageFile);
            IBuffer SecuredData = await SampleDataProtectionStream("LOCAL = user", data); 
            EncryptedFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("EncryptedFile" + storageFile.FileType, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); 
            await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(EncryptedFile, SecuredData);   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Details.Text = ($"Error processing command for '{storageFile.Name}':\n {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        else
        {  
          // Do nothing.    
        }
    }

    public async Task<IBuffer> SampleDataProtectionStream(String descriptor, IBuffer buffMsg)
    {  
        DataProtectionProvider Provider = new DataProtectionProvider(descriptor);
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream inputData = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream(); 
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream protectedData = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();      
        IOutputStream outputStream = inputData.GetOutputStreamAt(0);      
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputStream);      
        writer.WriteBuffer(buffMsg);  
        await writer.StoreAsync();  
        await outputStream.FlushAsync(); 

        IInputStream source = inputData.GetInputStreamAt(0); 
        IOutputStream dest = protectedData.GetOutputStreamAt(0);  
        await Provider.ProtectStreamAsync(source, dest);  
        await dest.FlushAsync(); 

       //Verify that the protected data does not match the original     
        DataReader reader1 = new DataReader(inputData.GetInputStreamAt(0));      
        DataReader reader2 = new DataReader(protectedData.GetInputStreamAt(0));  
        await reader1.LoadAsync((uint)inputData.Size);  
        await reader2.LoadAsync((uint)protectedData.Size);      
        IBuffer buffOriginalData = reader1.ReadBuffer((uint)inputData.Size);      
        IBuffer buffProtectedData = reader2.ReadBuffer((uint)protectedData.Size); 
        if (CryptographicBuffer.Compare(buffOriginalData, buffProtectedData)) 
        {
            throw new Exception("ProtectStreamAsync returned unprotected data"); 
        }
        // Return the encrypted data. 
        return buffProtectedData; 
        }
```

> UPDATE : I tested this code too;

```
if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
        {
            try 
            {
                FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
                openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
                openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
                openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
                StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
                
                IBuffer data = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
                IBuffer SecuredData = await SampleDataProtectionStream("LOCAL = user", data); 
                EncryptedFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("EncryptedFile" + file.FileType, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); 
                await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(EncryptedFile, SecuredData);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Details.Text = ($"Error occured while processing command for '{storageFile.Name}':\n{ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: on which line do you get the exception?

Comment: I get the exception at line 12 at the code which I posted. >> Details.Text = ($"Error processing command for '{storageFile.Name}':\n {ex.Message}");

Comment: Well, line 12 is inside your catch block, of course you'll see your error there. The question is, in which line the exception was raised. Did you debug your code?

Comment: Hey I'm sorry. The exception raises at line 6 in my code.

Comment: Now line 6 is only a little bit better as an answer than line 12, because line 6 is your call to `SampleDataProtectionStream`, so it happens inside that function. When you debug, step into your functions with `F11` instead of step over with `F10`! But I guess the answer below might already help to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception from HRESULT : 0XC0000225

I have tested with above code and open file with `FileOpenPicker` it works well, it could [encrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/data-protection) file and make file in local storage. And error `0XC0000225` means can't find the file, please check if `storageFile` is null.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        try
        {
            IBuffer data = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
            IBuffer SecuredData = await SampleDataProtectionStream("LOCAL = user", data);
            var EncryptedFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("EncryptedFile" + file.FileType, CreationCollisionOpt
            await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(EncryptedFile, SecuredData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Details.Text = ($"Error processing command for '{file.Name}':\n {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
         
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I replaced my code with  `FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
   StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();  IBuffer SecuredData = await SampleDataProtectionStream("LOCAL = user", file);`  But it still raises the above exception.

Comment: Could you share a code sample for us, I will test base on that.

Comment: I updated my code with new changes. Thanks for your help btw.